# strategy for simulating hover action using jquery ui slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

We're trying to come up with a way to trigger the tool-tip events on jquery charts such as [this one from rickshaw](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/examples/lines.html) by controlling the event from a jquery ui slider along the bottom (x) axis.

Therefore as a user slides the slider along the axis, the chart behaves as though the mouse was being dragged left to right across it. To simplify things the slider and the chart would be the same width. Can anyone suggest a way i might be able to make this happen in jquery/javascript?

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting question, but what have you tried? Setting a jsfiddle would be great.

Comment: heya - not really sure where to start with this so kind of looking for some initial ideas at this stage. My initial idea is to keep sampling the mouse's position at regular intervals (every few ms) whilst the slider is being slid, and then trigger a hover action some 100px further up the page with the same x coordinates. I guess is this likely to work? - obviously the other way would be to get into the guts of the chart plugin, but really at a loss how to make that happen...

Comment: possible: create a enclosing div and place the div containing chart behind it with proper overflow: hidden. then on moving the slider set the chart div's x,y position to simulate horizontal drag.